# SignalR - Forever frame transport overloading the DOM

Tags: signalr

I have a SignalR implementation that takes in about 15 messages a second, and updates the DOM via Knockout. I experience sever degredation in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox.

It turns out that the ForeverFrame transport never cleans up the messages, and as such, the DOM overloads after about 10 minutes, the browser becomes unresponsive, and ulimately crashes.

If I short circuit the start up to only use long polling, everything is peachy.

Are there known issues with the forever frame transport? Is there a reason I shouldn't just force it to use WebSockets/Long Polling?

I'm using signalR-0.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

> I experience sever degredation in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox.

You meant client degradation right?

in 0.5.2 we clean up the dom every 50 messages, not sure why you're seeing that behavior:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/SignalR/Scripts/jquery.signalR.js#L962

Comment: Thanks for the follow up David.  I did put some watches here, and although it does appear to clean it up, for some reason, the file itself seems to continue to grow:  I can watch its size increase in the VS debugger.  Its quite odd.  The file is:  

connect?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=someConnectionId&connectionData=[{"name":"SomeHub"}]&tid=1&frameId=3  

So the JS code is behaving correctly, but there is a residual, growing file. No idea whats causing this, as the counts from connection.frameMessageCount seem correct.